# Cannot access state inside fetch in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

In React Native, I have the following:

```
import React, { Component }                                         from 'react';
import PropTypes                                                    from 'prop-types';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight }               from 'react-native';
import Immutable                                                    from 'immutable';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: '20%',
  },
});

export default class VirtualFenceBottom extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { markers: this.props.markers  };
  }

  populateMarkers = () => {
    let markersVar = this.state.markers;
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/virtualFence', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }}).then(function(response){
          console.log('GET markers success');

          // Parse it as JSON
          parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response["_bodyInit"]);

          console.log('response after JSON.parse: ',parsedResponse);

          if (parsedResponse.length > 0) {
            //update state here
            console.log('parsedResponse in if statement: ',parsedResponse);
            // this.setState({markers: parsedResponse});
          } else {
            console.log('There were no markers in db');
          }



          console.log('markersVar: ',markersVar);
          // console.log('this.state.markers after setState: ',this.state.markers);

        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log('GET markers error');
          console.log("GET markers error: ",error);
        });
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.populateMarkers}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Populate markers from DB</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }}
```

All goes as expected, except I cannot access state directly inside `fetch`. Strangely, I can access it inside the containing function with `markerVar`. It seems there is a particular issue with `fetch` itself.

My goal is to update the state with the response. None of the existing answers for similar questions seem to work in my case. What do I do?

UPDATE 1: Added the code for the entire component.

UPDATE 2: Fixed a misspelling of the `parsedResponse` variable that was causing one part of the error.

Comment: Is this a method inside of a component?

Comment: Yes. I've added the code for the entire component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callbacks that are called in response to `fetch` results are just unbuond functions.
Try this:

```
}}).then(function(response){
    console.log('this', this); // see that 'this' is not
                               // what you expect it to be
```

Note, that `function() { ...}` in javascript creates closure that captures all local variables (including your `marketsVar`, but **not** _this__.

So, 'this' points into 'window' variable which doesn't have state (usually).

To fix this issue, you can

1) use fat arrow functions `then` and in `catch` handlers:(we're in 2018!, your toolchain handles it for sure):

```
fetch(...)
    .then(() => {
         this.setState(...) // this is defined. magic!
```

2) create alias to `this` - `that` is used sometimes:

```
var that = this;
fetch(...)
    .then(function() {
         that.setState(...); // that is defined in same way as marketsVar
    })
```

3) `bind` your handlers manually but that's ugly as hell so i don't recommend it.

Comment: The fat arrow functions did it! Yes, when I tried to console log `this` outside and inside `fetch`, I got different objects. Suggestion 2 also worked. However, suggestion 3 did NOT work here for some reason--I'd previously tried that both in the constructor and in render without success.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that this function exists *inside of* the component, otherwise it will not have access to the lexically scoped `this.state` method.

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {

  state = { val: 0 }

  myMethod = () => {
    this.setState({ val: 2 })
  }
}
```

Also consider whenever you pluck values from state, keeping the names consistent. For example:

```
const { markers } = this.state
```

Comment: It does exist inside the component. I've added the full code for more clarity. Please note that, as I mention in the post, `this.state` is currently accessible within the function, but not within the `fetch` promise chain. That's the weird part of it all.

Also please note that `marketsVar` is just there to make a point--that it can access `this.state` inside the function but outside `fetch`. In the final, working incarnation of the code, this variable will be removed.